# If in a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is true that $(A\cup B)^\circ=A^\circ\cup B^\circ$ for all $A,B\subseteq X$ then $X$ is discrete.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ s topological space so that $(A\cup B)^\circ=A^\circ\cup B^\circ$ for all $A,B\subseteq X$. Show that $X$ is discrete.

I trye with this exercise using that $\overline{A}=A\cup \rm{Fr}(A)=A^\circ\cup \rm{Fr}(A)$ but i can't show the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any subset $A$ of $X$, from the hypothesis we obtain $(A \cup A^c)^o = X = A^o \cup (A^c)^o$, hence $A^o = ((A^c)^o)^c$ ($A^o$ and $(A^c)^o$ are disjoint since $A$ and $A^c$ are). Now note that $(A^c)^o \subset A^c$ hence $A = (A^c)^c \subset ((A^c)^o)^c = A^o$, so that $A = A^o$ holds for all subsets $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a subset of $X$ that is not closed, so we have $p \in \overline{A}$ with $p \notin A$. Then $p \notin A^\circ$ and $p \notin (X\setminus A)^\circ$ but $p \in X^\circ = (A \cup (X\setminus A))^\circ$.

So if the identity were to hold, all subsets of $X$ are closed so $X$ is discrete.